# Monotouch - Set TintColor of UISearchBar

Tags: xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using a UISearchDisplayController and I'm trying to set the TintColor of the UISearchBar. The problem is that the color does not come though correctly. In interface builder the color of the search bar is correct after setting the tint property, but when the app runs, the search bar will be the same color, just a lot lighter. E.g. If I set the TintColor to black in interface builder it looks right in the designer, but when I run the app the color will come though medium grey.

I have also tried setting it in code like below, with no luck.

```
SearchDisplayController.SearchBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
```

Any Ideas? I'm a bit lost on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in iOS 5/6. Happens to me when I connect the search bar to a search display controller, but not otherwise.

How I (strangely) fixed it:

Add a segmented controller to your view, change it's tint color to your desired color. Now you will get the right color on your search bar as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it in Xcode but, API wise, `UISearchBar` has both a `BackgroundColor` and a `TintColor` and they are not identical. What you describe (grey'ing) is normal when using `TintColor` while using `BackgroundColor` should give you a pure color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried all combinations of the above two properties but cant seem to get it right. How should the values be set? Both to the same color?